# How do I connect my Expression Engine Site to Google Search Console?

Tags: search, seo, google

I'm not very familiar with Expression Engine. I normally use Weebly, Wordpress, Wix, etc. I'm having a hard time connecting my site to my search console. Not sure where to put HTML tag or which process works the easiest with Expression Engine. There doesn't seem to be any advance SEO settings through Exp. Engine.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean, you just upload the HTML file provided by Google to your webspace, usually right next to EE's index.php at the top of your public_html directory. That's not really EE-specific, is it?

Also, not sure what "advanced SEO settings" would be to you. You can certainly create keywords and such; if you don't want to to it by hand, as it were, take a look at [SEO Lite](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/seolite).